# How to backup and restore Google Docs files?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, backup

If I download Google Docs or Google Sheets files from Google Drive to a local hard disk using [rclone](https://rclone.org/) or [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout), I end up getting files in MS Office format (.docx., .xlsx etc.).

Now, I can edit those files, but when I upload them to Google Drive again, Google Drive will create a new copy when I edit them on Drive again, so I always end up with duplicate files.

Is there any way to download Google Docs (or Sheets) files in the original Google Docs format?

Or is there any way how I can upload the files to Drive so that they will be converted back to original Google Docs files?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to download Google Docs (or Sheets) files in the original Google Docs format?

Not in the way that this could be generally understood but it's possible to [Work on Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?hl=en)

> Or is there any way how I can upload the files to Drive so that they will be converted back to original Google Docs files?

Google documents, spreadsheets, slides that were converted to MS Office files formats could be converted back to Google file formats but they will have new ids; they can't be easily merged into the original documents. The not easy way is selecting all the orginal content and replace it by the new version. You could do this manually or programmatically.

Related Google APIs:

- [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/)
- [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)
- [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start)

Comment: How would I go about the "not easy way"? Is there an existing tool I can use? Or an API I could use as a developer?

Comment: @tmh: I added links to some APIs.